# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command Original error: Error executing adbExec

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\German\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 3af689100106 install -g 'C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk: Security exception: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:445) at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(Package'; Code: '1'

Comment: My configuration is {
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "9",
  "deviceName": "pine",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator1",
  "appPackage": "com.miui.calculator",
  "appActivity": "com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity"
}

Comment: Provide details about what you are trying to do and how you arrived at this error

Answer (score 0):

Observing your error logs, it seems to be PERMISSION ISSUE.

Ensure that all three options (whichever available on your Mobile OS) are checked/selected from your device.

```
Developer Options -> USB debugging
Developer Options -> USB debugging (Security settings)
Developer Options -> Install via USB
```